# Nginx request times out from browser, but it works through postman or curl

Tags: http, nginx, browser, connection-timeout, ufw

I can successfully http to domain though postman and curl:

```
http://bstevens.dev
curl -I http://bstevens.dev
```

Background:

- I followed the Digital Ocean Ubuntu initial set up and nginx install documents.
- I have triple checked steps, permission settings and file ownerships, it lines up with the docs.
- Only one change to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, as suggested by docs
- `server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;`
- I have not installed Let's encrypt.
- My droplet is ubuntu 20.04
- I followed setup directions for ufw

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp (Nginx HTTP)        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (Nginx HTTP (v6))   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Resolved

I have resolved this issue, it was the domain name: `bstevens.dev`
Any domain name ending in `.dev` uses the HSTS protocol.

```
HSTS is HTTP Strict Transport Security: a way for sites to elect to always use HTTPS.
```

I was searching nginx and ufw for this directive but discovered it is built in to `.dev`

```
Every .dev domain is on the HSTS preload list, which makes HTTPS required on all connections.
```

Thanks to [howard-roark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5491213/howard-roark) for confirming that browsers were seeing the HTTPS protocol for bstevens.dev and pointing me in the right direction with HSTS.

Comment: Nice that is very interesting!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is happening because the Browser is trying to access the site via https.  If you open the Network tab you can see this: [image]

There is an example [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/681635/nginx-browser-rewriting-http-request-to-https-when-not-wanted) that may be applicable.  I think you should approach this as understanding what is causing the Browser to try to connect via https.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I had noticed the browser changes the http into a https request. Yes,  something on my server is triggering the browser to do this. Hope to find it soon.